# Como pasar una variable desde un formulario html a un modal con javascript ( Ajax)

Tags: php, html, ajax, bootstrap

Acá se crea un listado con todos los usuario traídos desde la base de datos con AJAX. Se traen todos los datos sin ningún problema y muestra lo que yo deseo... adicional a esto dentro del lista se hace referencia a editar o eliminar dicho usuario.

```
<a href="#deleteUsuarioModal" data-target="#deleteUsuarioModal" class="btn btn-primary delete" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-id="<?php echo $user_id;?>">
```

Este modal se abre al darle clic en la etiqueta `<a>` mencionada anteriormente. Pero el `$user_id` no llega al modal, aunque se tenga el mismo nombre no se lleva el `user_id` seleccionado.

```
<div id="deleteUsuarioModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <form name="delete_usuario" id="delete_usuario">
       <div class="modal-header">
         <h4 class="modal-title">Eliminar Usuario</h4>
         <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
       </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
         <p>¿Seguro que quieres eliminar este registro?</p>
         <p class="text-warning"><small>Con esta accion el usuario quedara inactivo.</small></p>
         <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id">
        </div>

       <div class="modal-footer">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" value="Cancelar">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Eliminar">
       </div>
       </form>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript para pasar la información usando AJAX al formulario de PHP para poder eliminar el dato. Ahora esta acción siendo el campo en el modal me queda vacío.

No veo cual es el error gramatical para este uso. Estoy aprendiendo a realizar esto.

```
    $('#delete_usuario').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
var button = $(event.relatedTarget)
var id = button.data('id')
$('#user_id').val(id)
})
$( "#delete_usuario" ).submit(function( event ) {
var parametros = $(this).serialize();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "./ajax_usu/eliminar_usuario.php",
data: parametros,
beforeSend: function(objeto){
$("#resultados").html("Enviando...");
},
success: function(datos){
$("#resultados").html(datos);
load(1);
$('#deleteUsuarioModal').modal('hide');
}
});
event.preventDefault();
});

Acá ejecuto el eliminar pero siempre el `user_id` me llega vacío.

<?php
if (empty($_POST['user_id'])){
$errors[] = "Id vacío.";
} elseif (!empty($_POST['user_id'])){
include_once './../../../config/config.php';
$user_id=intval($_POST['user_id']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Tienes mal la variable id.

```
var id = button.data('id')
```

Debería ser

```
var id = button.data('data-id')
```

Ya que data-id es un atributo. Deberías llamarlo por el nombre que le indicaste.
con Jquery también podrías hacerlo así.

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

Tampoco veo que en los parámetros estés enviando el ID. Agregalo al final del serialize()

```
data: $(this).serialize() + '&user_id=' + id,
```